# Как лучше задать ширину 3-м блокам с float:left

Tags: css

Есть блок контейнер - 600px к примеру
И есть задача (довольно часто встречаемая) поместить туда 3 блока одинаковой ширины, с отступами между собой.
Суть в том, что используя float:left, в голову лезут решения только через flex, но нужно сделать именно через float'ы
Есть у кого какие идеи?

В моём решении, из-за наличия у двух блоков-обёрток padding-right: 30px и padding-right: 0 у последнего, 3-й блок, конечно же, шире двух других визуально.

p.s. Просто подставить одинаковые padding-left и padding-right как в бутстрапе не получится, ибо нужно, чтобы блоки прижимались к краям контейнера.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.row{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

.row:after, .row:before{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.block-wr{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.block-wr:last-child{
  padding-right: 0;
}

.block{
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">Я меньше, потому что имею padding :(</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">Я меньше, потому что имею padding :(</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">А я больше :), но скоро создатель меня уничтожит :(</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отрицательные значения `margin` у родителя не вариант поставить и использовать одинаковые отступы у блоков? Если речь идет о том, что блоки должны быть с границами или фоном, то вложите оформляемый блок c cjlth;bvsv в еще один (у которых будет float и отступы одинаковые) и задавайте ему стили оформления. Если все же менять html не хотите, тогда задавайте отступы через hth-child.

Answer (score 1):

У нас 2 промежутка между блоками по 30 пикселей итого 60 пикселей. 3 блока, значит 60/3 по 20 пиксей отступа на блок. Первому ставим справа, по середине с обоих сторон, последнему слева.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.row{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

.row:after, .row:before{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.block-wr{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.block-wr:first-child{
  padding-right:20px;
  padding-left:0px;
  }
  
.block-wr:last-child{
  padding-right:0px;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.block{
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">Я меньше, потому что имею padding :(</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">Я меньше, потому что имею padding :(</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">А я больше :), но скоро создатель меня уничтожит :(</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.row{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

.row:after, .row:before{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.block-wr{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.block-wr:last-child{

}

.block{
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">Я меньше, потому что имею padding :(</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">Я меньше, потому что имею padding :(</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-wr">
      <div class="block">А я больше :), но скоро создатель меня уничтожит :(</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```